# How to get the diagonal pixels in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am using a code like this

```
for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
```

By using this code I will get each pixel like`(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)` up to `(height,width)`. Now I wanted to get only the diagonal pixels so what code should I use?

Comment: You could just user the variable `row` for both col and row. Alternatively, to make the code more readable, you could set `col = row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two loops you are just running all the cells. If you just want the diagonal choose the preferential axis (assuming your image isn't square) and do:

```
 for i in range(height):
      print(image[i,i]) # syntax on the image object will depend on what you are using
```

, if your image is square (width == height) you can use any of the dimensions. If it's not you'll have to use the smaller.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use numpy.diagional

```
import numpy as np
image_diagionals = np.diagional(image)
```